# Como actualizar una bd de otra db sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, centos

Recientemente instale Centos y aqui instale mssql, todo bien, restaure un .bak de la db en produccion, lo que intento es que se actualicen las tablas de la db de produccion a esta que sera la de pruebas.

Intente con esto

```
SELECT * INTO CATALOGO_TICKETS (SELECT * FROM [192.168.1.13].db.dbo.CATALOGO_TICKETS)
```

me mando este error
Msg 263, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Must specify table to select from.
Msg 1038, Level 15, State 5, Line 1
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Comment: Creo que necesitas montar un linked server y, ahí sí, halar los datos a través de él.

Comment: @Alfabravo Ya lo tengo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema pasa porque no estás definiendo qué debe ir dentro de CATALOGO_TICKETS. Si la fuente es la subconsulta, esta debe declararse como el conjunto desde el que se extrae la info (es decir, va en el FROM). Está [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584093/236345) en SOen para confirmar esta hipótesis :)
Es importante, además, que la subconsulta tenga un alias.

```
SELECT *
INTO CATALOGO_TICKETS 
FROM (SELECT * FROM [192.168.1.13].db.dbo.CATALOGO_TICKETS) [myremote]
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero, necesitas entender la diferencia entre `SELECT...INTO` e `INSERT INTO...SELECT`.
El primero, creará una tabla basada en el resultado de una consulta (SELECT) y el segundo insertará los datos a una tabla ya existente.

Corrigiendo tu sentencia, estás repitiendo el SELECT cuando sólo deberías agregar el FROM.

```
SELECT * 
INTO CATALOGO_TICKETS --Si se comenta esta linea, debe funcionar como un SELECT normal.
FROM [192.168.1.13].db.dbo.CATALOGO_TICKETS;
```

Pero yendo un poco más allá, creo que lo que realmente necesitas es usar INSERT INTO

```
INSERT INTO CATALOGO_TICKETS 
/*(
columna1,
columna2,
columna3,
columnaN
)*/
--Si se comenta todo lo previo a esta linea, debe funcionar como un SELECT normal.
SELECT columna1, columna2, columna3, columnaN     
FROM [192.168.1.13].db.dbo.CATALOGO_TICKETS;
```

De cualquier forma, creo que lo más sencillo sería estar restaurando respaldos de producción en la base de datos de pruebas. Así puedes validar que los respaldos sirven en caso de algún problema, evitas estar leyendo constantemente al servidor de producción, reduces el tráfico de la red y mantienes la seguridad de la información productiva.